pd.to_datetime() not working for old dates
When trying to convert the "Date" field of a pandas DataFrame using pd.to_datetime(), I get an "OutOfBoundsDatetime" error only when the date is before Year 1700 (otherwise the conversion works fine). Any help?
df = pd.read_excel('Timeline_SecondMillenialH2.xlsx')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

First 2 records of the Excel file for reference:

Error:
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1516-01-01 00:00:00


Cf. here. That's not possible with pd.to_datetime. You can use pd.Period as a workaround. Split on -, otherwise following the suggested duplicates.

Yes. This answers my question. Thanks!
